# TryReset CancellationSource .NET Standard

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-standard, .net-7.0, cancellation-token

We're "downgrading" a net7.0 project to netstandard2.0. Most of the code seems to be good but we get an error on that it cannot find the TryReset method.

```
 cancellationTokenSource.TryReset(); <-- TryReset method cannot be found
 cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(10000);
```

What would the netstandard2.0 equivalent to TryReset be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [the implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs,477) there is no "direct" equivalent since managing internal state is involved. You can use [conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation) to leverage the method for cases when the library is used with .NET6 + ([when it was introduced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.tryreset?view=net-8.0#applies-to)):

```
#if NET6_0_OR_GREATER
cancellationTokenSource.TryReset();
// ...
#else
cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
#endif

cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(10000);
```

Answer (score 2):

The netstandard2.0 equivalent to [`TryReset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.tryreset) is to discard the existing `CancellationTokenSource`, and instantiate a new one.